# the installer script is not firing magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, setup, installer

i have setup the resource like the following at config file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <DigitalHorizons_Att>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </DigitalHorizons_Att>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <att>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>DigitalHorizons_Att</module>
                    <frontName>att</frontName>
                </args>
            </att>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <digitalhorizons_att_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>DigitalHorizons_Att</module>
                    <class>DigitalHorizons_Att_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </digitalhorizons_att_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

this is not fires the installer scripts at

> local\DigitalHorizons\Att\sql\digitalhorizons_att_setup\install-0.1.0.php

when i delete  DigitalHorizons_Att_Model_Resource_Setup class 
at app\code\local\DigitalHorizons\Att\Model\Resource\Setup.php

it says the following error,

> Warning: include(DigitalHorizons\Att\Model\Resource\Setup.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   E:\wamp\www\sample\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

the following content is there is at the installer file,

```
<?php
   echo 'Running This Upgrade: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";
   die("Exit for now");
?>
```

Comment: you install file path will be **local\DigitalHorizons\Att\sql\digitalhorizons_att_setup\install-0.1.0.php**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

**local\DigitalHorizons\Att\sql\att_setup\install-0.1.0.php**

to

**local\DigitalHorizons\Att\sql\digitalhorizons_att_setup\inst‌​all-0.1.0.php**

make sure your module version is same `0.1.0` in config.xml

```
<modules>
    <DigitalHorizons_Att>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </DigitalHorizons_Att>
</modules>
```

and also check remove the entry of `digitalhorizons_att_s‌​etup` from **core_resource** table

Comment: yes, now the installer is at app\code\local\DigitalHorizons\Att\sql\digitalhorizons_att_setup\install-0.1.0.php

Comment: but still it is not working

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick updated the answer follow that

Comment: there is no entry in core_resource , because it is the first time. also i edited the directory name to digitalhorizons_att_s‌​etup from att_s‌​etup, even it is not working

Comment: try with file name  `mysql4-install-0.1.0.p‌​hp`

Comment: run this query in phpmyadmin to check the entry **SELECT * FROM `core_resource` WHERE `code` = 'digitalhorizons_att_s‌​etup'** or **SELECT * FROM `core_resource` WHERE `version` = '0.1.0'**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51592/discussion-between-manokarthick-karthick-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick what was the issue?

Comment: @quisar   a small mistake, that was 
</modules> <> ..</> </modules> tag was missing,

Answer (score 1):

you need to add following node in your config.xml update as follow

you have define connection and read and write nodes in `config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<DigitalHorizons_Att>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</DigitalHorizons_Att>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <att>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>DigitalHorizons_Att</module>
                <frontName>att</frontName>
            </args>
        </att>
    </routers>
</frontend>
<global>
    <resources>
        <digitalhorizons_att_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>DigitalHorizons_Att</module>
                <class>DigitalHorizons_Att_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </digitalhorizons_att_setup>
        <digitalhorizons_att_write>   
            <connection>         
                <use>core_write</use>     
            </connection> 
        </digitalhorizons_att_write> 

        <digitalhorizons_att_read>     
            <connection>        
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>   
        </digitalhorizons_att_read>
    </resources>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: i copy-pasted above nodes in config.xml , but still it is not working.

Comment: @manokarthickkarthick have you deleted your entry from `core_resource` table?

Comment: there is no entry in the core_resource table

Comment: it is the first time i'm creating the installer, any way it does not run, so there was no entry in core_resource table

Comment: also change the suggestion by qaisar

Comment: that already i changed,